# Trying to get bootstrap collapse opening from right to left horizontally

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zu5ftdjx/65/) here where I would like the content to collapse from the right side opening up to the left. Is this possible?

```css
.collapse {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.collapse.in {
  display: block;
  visibility: visible;
}
tr.collapse.in {
  display: table-row;
}
tbody.collapse.in {
  display: table-row-group;
}
.collapsing {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition-property: height, visibility;
  transition-property: height, visibility;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.35s;
  transition-duration: 0.35s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
}
.collapsing.width {
  -webkit-transition-property: width, visibility;
  transition-property: width, visibility;
  width: 0;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">
  Horizontal Collapsible
</button>

<div id="container" style="width:300px;height:400px;border:1px solid black;">
  <div id="demo" class="collapse in width" style="background-color:yellow;">
    <div style="padding: 20px; overflow:hidden; width:300px;">
      Here is my content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: [Check this](http://jsfiddle.net/fauzi/q9GLR/)

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/zu5ftdjx/66/)**

Just add `float:right` to your `element-#demo` as below:

```
<div id="demo" class="collapse in width" style="background-color:yellow;float:right;">
```

> Note - This will give you some overflow issue and I hope you will be able to fix it since width and height are predefined by you